# OpenLayers 6 HeatMap - Uncaught Error: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, openlayers

We have a an OpenLayers application based upon v6 which is blowing up with this error. It was working well yesterday, and today it is not. We're not finding where we broke something. The error is coming from some asynchronous event in the renderer (no obvious top-level function in the backtrace). Lots of single-letter function names in the ol libraries. We're needing some help figuring out where to go next.

http://www.nufosmatic.com/nufosmatic/html/frame.html

The "Ol6 Maps Heatmap" page...

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that Chrome went toxic. The page would render in Brave, Edge, and Firefox but not in Chrome. We closed all of our Chrome windows (Windows 10, Chrome Version 91.0.4472.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and then made certain that all of the background processes were dead and re-started the browser. Everything is working everywhere again.

The error was buried deep in the rendering logic in OL, and we were not going to be able to figure this out. Fortunately, we thought to try another browser just to see.